# Linked list method help c#

Tags: c#

Heres my linked list program from scratch. I've managed to get my list to display, but now i want to display the number of items in the list as an int, which in my case would be 3.

Can someone give me a few pointers

Main:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkList testList = new LinkList();

            testList.AddItem(5);
            testList.AddItem(10);
            testList.AddItem(12);
            testList.DisplayItems();

            Console.WriteLine(testList.NumberOfItems()); /// Still to do


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Class for LinkList:

```
  class LinkList
       {
        private Link list = null; //default value – empty list

        public void AddItem(int item) //add item to front of list
        {
            list = new Link(item, list);
        }

        public void DisplayItems() // Displays items in list
        {
            Link temp = list;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp.Data);
                temp = temp.Next;
            }

        }

        public int NumberOfItems() // returns number of items in list
        {
            Link temp = list;
            while (temp != null) 
            {
             /// How can i display the number of items in list as an int?
            }    


            }


    }

}
```

Class for link:

```
class Link
{
    private int data;
    private Link next;

    public Link(int item) //constructor with an item
    {
        data = item;
        next = null;
    }
    public Link(int item, Link list) //constructor with item and list
    {
        data = item;
        next = list;
    }

    public int Data //property for data
    {
        set { this.data = value; }
        get { return this.data; }
    }

    public Link Next //property for next
    {
        set { this.next = value; }
        get { return this.next; }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? Where are you stuck in your quest to get the count?

Comment: If you know how to iterate through the list and display the items, you know how to iterate through the list and count them. Also, if you create a counter and have your `AddItem` method increment this counter, then `NumberOfItems` could be implemented in O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Basically you´d loop your list (as done when Displaying it) and increment an internal counter

Comment: If you did not know, `i++` will increment a variable by one, `i--` will decrement a variable by one.

Answer (score 1):

So, declare a private variable for the number of items, then on the Add Method increase it.
At the end, add a Property to return this private variable as a Public Int.

This should work:

```
       public class LinkList
       {
          private Link list = null; //default value – empty list

          private numberOfItems = 0;

          public void AddItem(int item) //add item to front of list
          {
              list = new Link(item, list);
              numberOfItems++;
          }

          public void DisplayItems() // Displays items in list
          {
              Link temp = list;
              while (temp != null)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(temp.Data);
                  temp = temp.Next;
              }

          }

          public int NumberOfItems
          {

              get {return numberOfItems; }

          }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your list (as done within `Display`)

```
public void DisplayItems() // Displays items in list
    {
        Link temp = list;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.Data);
            temp = temp.Next;
        }

    }

    public int NumberOfItems() // returns number of items in list
    {
        Link temp = list;
        int i = 0;
        while (temp != null) 
        {
            temp = temp.Next;
            i++;
        }    
        return i;
    }
```